# Dojo deferred not being resolved

Tags: javascript, dojo, deferred

I have the following javascript

```
var setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred = new Deferred();
makePrefillCallsDeferred.then(lang.hitch(this, function () {
    setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred = this._setPrefillVehicleValue();
    //this is being called
    setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred.then(function () {
        alert("resolving recall inside");
        recallDfd.resolve(data);
    });
}));  

//NOT being called
setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred.then(function () {
    alert("resolving recall");
    recallDfd.resolve(data);
});
```

note, any `...deferred` and `...dfd` variables will be `Deferred` objects

My issue, is that the `setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred.then()` that is isolated is not being triggered when the deferred is being resolved, yet the exact same code, moved into a closer scope is being triggered.  This is just a snippet of the code, but I basically need the isolated `then()` call to execute, the one that is currently being is called is just for debugging purposes to see what's going wrong.

Anybody got any idea why the one I want is not being triggered?

I should add that `this._setPrefillVehicleValue()` is returning a resolved deferred object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the outside `setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred.then` call is made, the value of `setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred` is the new `Deferred()` object that you created since `makePrefillCallsDeferred` is asynchronous. So it is not based on the deferred object returned by `this._setPrefillVehicleValue`.

You could resolve the outside Deferred object when `this._setPrefillVehicleValue` is resolved, which I think will get you the desired result:

```
var setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred = new Deferred();
makePrefillCallsDeferred.then(lang.hitch(this, function () {
    this._setPrefillVehicleValue().then(function () {
        setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred.resolve();
    });
}));  

setPrefillVehicleValueDeferred.then(function () {
    alert("resolving recall");
    recallDfd.resolve(data);
});
```